# Nanoparticle Alloys (Gold-Silver) not forming

Tags: nanotechnology, alloy, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I have synthesised what I thought were gold-silver alloys at various different compositions. 
The UV/vis data showed that nanoparticles alloys with a majority of the composition made from gold had one plasmon band, indicating they were alloys.
However with nanoparticle alloys where the composition is mainly silver, the UV/vis data shows two plasmon bands, indicating the presence of segregated gold and silver nanoparticles which are not alloyed.

Could anyone explain why this has happened?

Comment: From a phase diagram perspective there isn’t a good one. I’d contemplate the nanoparticle growth process and how a silver rich vs gold rich particle forms.

Comment: Can you add how you made the particles. It would be helpful to know if you did a simultaneous reduction and with what materials.

Comment: Yes I carried out a simultaneous reduction using sodium borohydride, the stabilizing agent is PDADMAC

Comment: I do intent to answer this just need to find a particular paper first.